# How to format or change the printing of SQL Queries in SQLAlchemy? Why ALL FAILED

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I would like to format the printing of SQL Queries in SQLAlchemy:

original data as below:

```
   name    days
   Alice   60
   Bob     52
   Mike    266
   Lucas   27
```

I would like to display as below format:

```
   name    days
   Alice   2
   Bob     1 22/30
   Mike    8 26/30
   Lucas   27/30
```

I tried to use below code to change `<class 'sqlalchemy.util._collections.result'>`, but I got the error of `can't set attribute`:

```
def get_days(days):
    if days % 30:
        return "{} {}/30".format(days // 30, days % 30)
    else:
        return str(int(days / 30))

def get_baby_detail:
    data = db.session.query(Baby.name,Baby.days).filter(Basy.id == id).first()
    data.days = get_days(data.days)
    return dict(data=data)
```

option 1 faild.

Then I tried to use below code to format the days, but I got the error of `unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'InstrumentedAttribute' and 'int'`

```
def get_baby_detail:
    days_format = case(
        [
            (Baby.days % 30, "{} {}/30".format(Baby.days // 30, Baby.days % 30))
        ],
        else_=str(int(Baby.days / 30))
        )
    data = db.session.query(Baby.name, days_format.label('days')).filter(Basy.id == id).first()
    return dict(data=data)
```

option 2 also failed.

All failed, is there someone who can help me with this issue? Thanks so much for any advice

Answer (score 2):

You get the "can't set attribute" error in the first approach because the `data` object is not mutable (in SQLAlchemy 1.4 it's a [Row](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Row), in earlier versions it's a [KeyedTuple](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple)).  I'm assuming that you are using SQLAlchemy 1.4.

You can get around this by not trying to assign directly to `data`: instead, assign to a new variable and update the dictionary that you are returning with the new value.

You can also use the [divmod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) built-in function to simplify the `get_days` function.

```py
def get_days(days):
    quotient, modulus = divmod(days, 30)
    if modulus:
        return "{} {}/30".format(quotient, modulus)
    else:
        return str(int(quotient))


def get_baby_detail(id_):
    data = db.session.query(Baby.name, Baby.days).filter(Baby.id == id_).first()
    got_days = get_days(data.days)
    return dict(data, days=got_days)
```